# join and groupby 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I have 2 data frames

```
df:ServicesA                         df:ServicesB
index      clientID    ServiceID_A  |  index    ClientID  ServiceID_B
0          A                 1      |  0          A           4
1          B                 2      |  1          B           5
2          C                 3      |  2          D           6
2          B                 4      |
```

I want to get a new df that shows those clients on df:ServicesB and how many servicesA those clients have. which would be something like this

```
index    ClientID With ServiceID_B        count(ServiceID_A)
0                   A                             1
1                   B                             2
2                   D                             0
```

I tried this:

I got a unique list of client ID's from df:ServicesB and create a new df called 'df'

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df_ServicesB['Client ID', ].unique(),columns=['Client ID'])
```

and then I use this lambda function that would take each client id from df and iterate through df:ServicesA count those rows that have a client id that mathes (which is equivalante to count the serviceidA on that dataframe

```
def getTotaldfServicesA(clientid):
  total_services = 0
  for index, row in df_ServicesA.iterrows():
    if row['ClientID'] == clientid:
      total_services += 1
  return total_services

df['Total_servicesA'] = df.apply(lambda row: getTotaldfServicesA(row['ClientID']),axis=1)
```

I 'believe' the formula works but I say 'I believe' becuase I technically haven't seen the resulting df as df_ServicesA is a very long list to iterate through and the number of clients on df_ServicesB is also long making the iteration process exponential to the point that the lambda function has been run a couple of times but either has failed with no error or it has timeout overnight and I've gotten disconnected by the time I get to my computer to see the result. Currently it's been running for 4 hours and I still don't get a resulting df dataset/frame.

maybe there's a more pythonic way to do this? or maybe a way to make it more efficient so it doesn't take forever?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your first dataframe and count the groups:

```
# Assuming that df:ServicesA is df_a
grouped = df_a.groupby("clientID").count()
>>> grouped

        ServiceID_A
clientID    
       A    1
       B    2
       C    1
```

After that you can left outer join the second dataframe on the grouped with the [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function:

```
# Assuming that df:ServicesB is df_b
joined = df_b[["ClientID"]].merge(grouped, left_on="ClientID",
                                  right_on="clientID", how="left").fillna(0)
>>> joined
    clientID    ServiceID_A
0          A            1.0
1          B            2.0
2          D            0.0
```

Comment: You get my accepted answer dude.. thank you so much! :). it makes sense for me to do it in 2 steps as you proposed and after I managed to adapt your approach to my datasets I got my resulting df just as I wanted. Again. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
I tested your dateframe with csv files, its working:

```
sA = pd.read_csv("ServicesA.csv")
sB = pd.read_csv("ServicesB.csv")
count_dict = sA.groupby(['ClientID']).size().to_dict()
count_dict.setdefault('D',0)
sB['count(ServiceID_A)'] = sB.ClientID.replace(count_dict)
```

Let me know if this is not working

Comment: Hi Saravanan, thank you so much for giving me a hand.
After I adapted your answer to my particular code and name conventions I get this error:
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'
should casting be done or coercion of some sort?

Comment: Convert your ClientID variable into Object and then try.

Answer (score 0):

You should always avoid is iterating over a DataFrame/ Series, it's very slow. It should be your last resource. There is almost always a better way.
In this case, you want to look into `groupby` and `merge`.
You should read these guides

1. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html
2. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

This will be much faster than using `iterrows`

```
>>> res = (
      df_ServicesB.merge(df_ServicesA, how='left', on='ClientID')
                  .groupby('ClientID', as_index=False)
                  [['ServiceID_A']].count()      
)
>>> res.columns = ["ClientID With ServiceID_B", "count(ServiceID_A)"]
>>> res

  ClientID With ServiceID_B  count(ServiceID_A)
0                         A                   1
1                         B                   2
2                         D                   0
```

Comment: Thank you Harry for info on when to use iteration, I knew it was not ideal but I'm pretty much a newbie on pandas and python in general so I do appreciate that input. I did manage to get your code working with my datasets but some how is duplicating the total of services A for each client with Services B. I possibly need to mention that both datasets/frames, have one or more services that belong to the same client id.